# No rule to make target `external/obpermissionjar/javalib/obpermissionjar-Pro20160628_1.0.9', needed by ..?

Tags: java, android, makefile, android-source

I want to add a 3rd lib in AOSP.First,I put the **.jar file in external/obpermission,and my Android.mk file are as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:=obpermission
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGES:=optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS:=JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH:=$(TARGET_OUT_JAVA_LIBRARIES)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=javalib/obpermissionjar-Pro20160628_1.0.9
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

But it builds failed with:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `external/obpermissionjar/javalib/obpermissionjar-Pro20160628_1.0.9', needed by `out/target/product/generic/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/obpermission_intermediates/obpermission'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Can you post the exact directory structure of the folder `obpermission`? The build system is telling you it cannot find the file located at `external/obpermissionjar/javalib/obpermissionjar-Pro20160628_1.0.9`, are you sure it's there?

Comment: /home/helloliu/WORKING_DIRECTORY/external/obpermissionjar/javalib/obpermissionjar-Pro20160628_1.0.9.jar;/home/helloliu/WORKING_DIRECTORY/external/obpermissionjar/Android.mk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to the following:

```
    LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE:=obpermission
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGES:=optional
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS:=JAVA_LIBRARIES
    LOCAL_MODULE_PATH:=$(TARGET_OUT_JAVA_LIBRARIES)
    LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=javalib/obpermissionjar-Pro20160628_1.0.9.jar
    include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

You were missing the trailing `.jar` for the file path. It's also a good idea to include the `LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)` but it's not required I don't believe.